# Why is my JSFiddle not working? (where to place script)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

When I run this on my computer, the numbers disappear and reappear when I check the boxes, as desired. I think there was a problem with attaching the external resource script. Where do I put the link to the library?

I'm having a problem formatting the code to required embed the fiddle, but go to j-s-f-iddle and add /codergirl789/k37jqj2c/2/

Comment: Find "External Resources" on the right side of the page

Comment: *"When I run this on my computer"* - what's "this" ..?

Comment: I already embedded the link to the jquery library – it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: When I run the code on pycharm it works fine, but when I copied and pasted it into the jsfiddle, it stopped working, presumably because of something related to the link to the external library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a double quote in your url for your external script.

Like this:

```
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js
```

I've updated a fiddle with the current url:

http://jsfiddle.net/gregborbonus/k37jqj2c/4/

Also, if you need to load jQuery, just click the Javascript button (top right of the javascript console with the gear next to it) and under "Frameworks and Extensions" drop down to the jQuery version you want.

Comment: Would be great if you could Mark it as answered.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new here.